# Alocação encadeada - Estrutura de dados - C

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados

Considere uma área de armazenamento de 5 nodos. Sobre esta área será montada uma lista simplesmente encadeada com ordenação crescente pelo campo INFO, de nome LISTA. Inicialmente crie a PND e o NODO-CABEÇA para deixar esta lista operacional. Após, mostre o comportamento da lista durante as seguintes operações:

1. Inclusão da informação VERDE
2. Inclusão da informação VERMELHO
3. Inclusão da informação LARANJA
4. Retirada da informação VERDE
5. Inclusão da informação OCRE
6. Inclusão da informação ROSA
7. Retirada da primeira informação na ordem lógica
8. Inclusão da informação PRETO
9. Inclusão da informação CINZA
10. Retirada da informação VERMELHO
11. Retirada da informação PRETO
12. Retirada da última informação na ordem lógica
13. Inclusão da informação BRANCO
14. Inclusão da informação LILÁS
15. Retirada da informação CINZA
16. Retirada da informação BRANCO

Meu código não da nenhum erro de compilação, porém o resultado não é o esperado. Alguém poderia me ajudar? Segue o meu código.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define TAMANHO 5

struct nodo {
    char info[8];
    int elo;
};

int disp, nc;
struct nodo lista[TAMANHO];

void cria_pnd(void) {
    int i = 0;
    while(i < TAMANHO -1) {
        lista[i].elo = i+1;
        i++;
    }
    lista[TAMANHO-1].elo = -1;
    disp = 0;
}

int obtem(void) {
    int aux;
    if(disp == -1)
        return(-1);
    aux = disp;
    disp = lista[disp].elo;
    return(aux);
 }

void cria_nc(void) {
    nc = obtem();
    if(nc == -1) {
        printf("\nNao pode criar NC. Programa abortado!");
        fflush(stdin);
        getchar();
        exit(1);
    }
    strcpy(lista[nc].info , "-1");
    lista[nc].elo = -1;
}

void libera(int indice) {
    lista[indice].elo = disp;
    disp = indice;
}

void inclusao(char valor) {
    int post, ant, indice;
    indice = obtem();
    if(indice == -1)
        printf("\nOVERFLOW");
    else {
        strcpy(lista[indice].info , "valor");
        ant = nc;
        post = lista[nc].elo;
        while(post != -1) {
            if(strcmp(valor , lista[post].info))
                break;
            ant = post;
            post = lista[post].elo;
        }
        lista[indice].elo = post;
        lista[ant].elo = indice;
        if (post == -1)
            strcpy(lista[nc].info , "indice");
        printf("\nInclusao efetuada");
    }
    fflush(stdin);
    getchar();
}

void retirada(char valor) {
    int ant, indice;
    if(lista[nc].elo == -1)
        printf("\nUNDERFLOW");
    else {
        ant = nc;
        indice = lista[nc].elo;
        while(indice != -1) {
            if(strcmp(valor , lista[indice].info))
                break;
            ant = indice;
            indice = lista[indice].elo;
        }
        if (indice == -1)
            printf("\nValor nao encontrado");
        else {
            lista[ant].elo = lista[indice].elo;
            if(lista[nc].elo == -1)
                strcpy(lista[nc].info , "-1");
            else if(lista[indice].elo == -1)
               strcpy(lista[nc].info , "ant");
            libera(indice);
            printf("\nRetirada efetuada");
        }
    }
    fflush(stdin); 
    getchar();
}

int main() {
    char valor[8];
    int op;

    cria_pnd();
    cria_nc();

    do {
        printf("\nInforme a operacao.");
        printf("\nDigite 1 para inclusao.");
        printf("\nDigite 2 para retirada.");
        printf("\nDigite 9 para sair.");
        printf("\n");
        scanf("%d", &op);

        switch(op) {
        case 1:
            inclusao(valor);
            break;
        case 2:
            retirada(valor);
            break;
        case 9:
            return 0;
        default:
            printf("\n");
            printf("\nInforme um valor valido.");
            printf("\n");
        }
    } while(op != 1 || op !=2 || op !=9);
}
```

Comment: O enunciado fala de lista simplesmente encadeada, mas você usa arrays (mesmo tendo um campo `elo`). Não era para você usar `malloc` e `free`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void retirada(char valor[]) //precisa ser uma string

void inclusao(char valor[]) //precisa ser um string
```

Troque `char` valor por `char valor[]`

isso cria um parâmetro capaz de receber uma string.

Se não colocar desta forma as funções strcpy e strcpm não irão funcionar. Eles precisam receber uma string.

Veja abaixo o código sem erros de compilação.

Agora estude ele e veja se a lista encadeada está OK

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define TAMANHO 5

struct nodo {
    char info[8];
    int elo;
};

int disp, nc;
struct nodo lista[TAMANHO];

void cria_pnd(void) {
    int i = 0;
    while(i < TAMANHO -1) {
        lista[i].elo = i+1;
        i++;
    }
    lista[TAMANHO-1].elo = -1;
    disp = 0;
}

int obtem(void) {
    int aux;
    if(disp == -1)
        return(-1);
    aux = disp;
    disp = lista[disp].elo;
    return(aux);
 }

void cria_nc(void) {
    nc = obtem();
    if(nc == -1) {
        printf("\nNao pode criar NC. Programa abortado!");
        fflush(stdin);
        getchar();
        exit(1);
    }
    strcpy(lista[nc].info , "-1");
    lista[nc].elo = -1;
}

void libera(int indice) {
    lista[indice].elo = disp;
    disp = indice;
}

void inclusao(char valor[]) //precisa ser um string
{
    int post, ant, indice;
    indice = obtem();
    if(indice == -1)
        printf("\nOVERFLOW");
    else {
        strcpy(lista[indice].info , "valor");
        ant = nc;
        post = lista[nc].elo;
        while(post != -1) {
            if(strcmp(valor , lista[post].info))
                break;
            ant = post;
            post = lista[post].elo;
        }
        lista[indice].elo = post;
        lista[ant].elo = indice;
        if (post == -1)
            strcpy(lista[nc].info , "indice");
        printf("\nInclusao efetuada");
    }
    fflush(stdin);
    getchar();
}

void retirada(char valor[]) //precisa ser uma string
{
    int ant, indice;
    if(lista[nc].elo == -1)
        printf("\nUNDERFLOW");
    else {
        ant = nc;
        indice = lista[nc].elo;
        while(indice != -1) {
            if(strcmp(valor , lista[indice].info))
                break;
            ant = indice;
            indice = lista[indice].elo;
        }
        if (indice == -1)
            printf("\nValor nao encontrado");
        else {
            lista[ant].elo = lista[indice].elo;
            if(lista[nc].elo == -1)
                strcpy(lista[nc].info , "-1");
            else if(lista[indice].elo == -1)
               strcpy(lista[nc].info , "ant");
            libera(indice);
            printf("\nRetirada efetuada");
        }
    }
    fflush(stdin);
    getchar();
}

int main() {
    char valor[8];
    int op;

    cria_pnd();
    cria_nc();

    do {
        printf("\nInforme a operacao.");
        printf("\nDigite 1 para inclusao.");
        printf("\nDigite 2 para retirada.");
        printf("\nDigite 9 para sair.");
        printf("\n");
        scanf("%d", &op);

        switch(op) {
        case 1:
            inclusao(valor);
            break;
        case 2:
            retirada(valor);
            break;
        case 9:
            return 0;
        default:
            printf("\n");
            printf("\nInforme um valor valido.");
            printf("\n");
        }
    } while(op != 1 || op !=2 || op !=9);
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado cara!

Comment: Disponha! Bom Estudo!